# Https Server for Android with Qt6

Tags: android, httpserver, qt6

I'm trying to build an https server on Android using Qt 6.3.0 since the qt module Qt HTTP Server is not available yet. Is it possible to code it from scratch? Is there any code that i can use or start with?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why do you need a server on android?

Comment: I need to access to an html file which is not local and without any internet connection

Comment: If you can use [Ktor](https://ktor.io/), then there are ways to embed the server in Android. Search for `android ktor server` on your favorite search tool, and you'll get various relevant results.

Comment: I actually need to use Qt and C++ @MartinMarconcini

Comment: @speryem Wym "**access** HTML file"? just read it? you don't need server for this.  
Also there are plenty of C++ HTTP servers that are probably better than Qt.

Comment: @ניר I mean open an html file and read it, it contains webGL components so it's more complicated.. and i need to use Qt so i can add the server to an existing application developped with Qt

Comment: I think what you are looking for is [`WebEngineView`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtwebengine-webengineview.html)

Comment: @ניר Unfortunetely, Qt WebEngine is not available on mobile platforms. It works only in macOS, Windows and on Linux but not on Android

Comment: so why can't you provide the link and open with native browser?

Comment: @ניר Because i want to have an independant and external application

Comment: I see... Anyways I can't see why Http server would help you, http server just handles requests and send  responses it does not show html filed.